# Dataset of US local, state, federal contact phone numbers?

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, government

I'm looking to create an app that facilitates U.S. Americans to contact local, state, or federal representative based on home address. I can use the already public shape-files to figure out the relevant municipalities but I can't find a centralized list of contact numbers.

Does anyone know of a comprehensive list of contact information for multiple levels of US government representatives?

Comment: i'd be very, very surprised if this exists in one list. you're going to have to do a lot of legwork to get this for state and local. also, imho, search by zip is flawed, so don't rely just on that. good luck.

Comment: That's what I figured but it was worth asking. I agree local/state is going to require a bit of legwork.

Comment: its definitely something we should have...along with addresses and emails...

Answer (score 1):

A Google spreadsheet is being crowdsourced for an attempt at the federal level, for DC and local offices.
[Federal Contact Information Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/174f0WBSVNSdcQ5_S6rWPGB3pNCsruyyM_ZRQ6QUhGmo/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true#)